# Is there an efficient algorithm for expression equivalence?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, decision-problem

e.g. $xy+x+y=x+y(x+1)$ ?

The expressions are from ordinary high-school algebra, but restricted to arithmetic addition and multiplication (e.g. $2+2=4; 2.3=6$), with no inverses, subtraction or division.  Letters are variables.

If it helps, we can forbid any expression representable with numeric values other than $1$; i.e. not $x^2$ nor $3x$ nor $4$:

- *multilinear*, no **powers** other than $1$: $x+xy \equiv x^1+x^1y^1$ is OK, but not $x^2+x^3y^4$, and not anything that could be represented as that, as in a full expansion to sum-of-products e.g. not $x(x+y) \equiv x^2+y$;
- *all one*, no **coefficients** other than $1$: $x+xy \equiv 1.x+1.xy$ is OK, but not $2x+3xy$, and not anything that could be represented as that, as in a full expansion to sum-of-products e.g. not $a(x+y)+x(a+b) \equiv 2ax+ay+bx$ ; and
- no **constants** other than $1$: again, in the fully expanded sum-of-products e.g. not $(a+1)+(b+1) \equiv a+b+2$

$Q.$ Is there an efficient algorithm to determine if two expressions are equivalent?

---

To illustrate, here's an inefficient brute-force algorithm with exponential time:

> expand both expressions fully to *sum-of-products*, which can easily be checked for equivalence (just ignore order, since commute/associate can reorder).

e.g.
$(a+b)(x+y) \rightarrow ax+ay+bx+by$
$a(x+y)+b(x+y) \rightarrow ax+ay+bx+by$

---

This seems a well-known problem - even high school students are taught manual ways to solve it. It's also solved by automated theorem provers/checkers, but they concentrate on more sophisticated aspects.

Here's a working online automated theorem prover: http://tryacl2.org/, which shows equivalence by finding a sequence of commute/associate/distribute etc:

$xy+x+y=x+y(x+1)$ ?
`(thm (=  (+ (* x y) x y)  (+ x (* y (+ x 1)))  ))` --- 188 steps

$y+x(y+1)=x+y(x+1)$ ?
`(thm (=  (+ y (* x (+ y 1)))  (+ x (* y (+ x 1)))  ))` --- 325 steps

*This is my first question here, so please let me know if I've chosen the wrong place, wrong tags, wrong way of describing/asking etc. Thanks!*
*NB: this question has been rewritten in response to comments*
*Thanks to all responders! I've learned a lot.*

Comment: The question here needs some clarification. What field are you operating over? Are the objects such as "$a$" and "$b$" in your expressions elements of the field or variables? Is it actually a field (i.e., do addition and multiplication have inverses)? Note that sum-of-products doesn't help because $(a_1+b_1)(a_2+b_2)\cdots(a_n+b_n)$ has exponetially many terms.

Comment: If the objects are variables, and subtraction is allowed, then you're essentially asking about polynomial identity testing, which has a randomized polynomial time algorithm by the [Schwartz–Zippel lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz%E2%80%93Zippel_lemma). $f(x)=g(x)$ iff $f(x)-g(x)=0$ and the basic idea is that a polynomial that isn't identically zero doesn't have many roots so, if you start guessing roots at random and find a lot of roots, there's a high probability that your polynomial was identically zero.

Comment: Thanks @DavidRicherby. Addition and multiplication don't have inverses (I described it as "arithmetic", thinking lack of inverses wouldn't matter, but as you're shown, it's significant in the S-Z lemma). Objects $a$ and $b$ are elements (like symbols in regular expressions). The underlying set is (the set of all) languages of symbols sets - like kleene algebra/regular expressions, but no order (and no star): *+* is language union; *.* is union of all combinations of symbol sets in the operand languages. Yes, I meant the sum-of-products algorithm as not in P. I'll edit.

Comment: You could also ask whether it's in coNP, or do you already know that?

Comment: Hrm...I believe your math rules are similar to that of boolean logic. Expanding it out is similar to the known task of converting a boolean expression to conjuntive normal form, which maps directly to 3SAT which is NP Complete. I'll be betting that a similar proof can show that your logic is also 3SAT-mappable and thus NP.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody mentioned this yet, but "if it is in NP I don't need to worry about finding a polynomial algorithm" doesn't make sense. Every problem in P is also in NP. You probably meant to ask whether the problem is NP-complete (or -hard).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I'm not familiar with coNP. Checking wikipedia, it seems to just be the complement. So here, wouldn't that be "are the expressions not equivalent" - it seems an identical question for a decision problem. But probably I don't understand.

Comment: @IdeaHat expanding it is $NP$, because just stating the answer takes exponential space (BTW: isn't sum-of-products closer to DNF than CNF?). But expanding it is part of one particular algorithm; maybe there's a cleverer way that avoids that. BTW I agree it seems similar to boolean algebra, but I haven't been able to find an equivalence e.g. $x \lor y$ includes both being true; but $x+y$ means either-or. We could use exclusive-or, but it nests differently: $(x \oplus y) \oplus z$ is also true is all the variables are true, whereas $(x+y)+z$ means just one of them (i.e. $\{\{x\},\{y\},\{z\}\}$).

Comment: @TomvanderZanden yes, solutions solved in polynomial time ($P$) are verifiable in polynomial time ($NP$), so $P \subseteq NP$. But - and maybe I'm wrong here - I feel the precise distinctions between $NP$, $NP-complete$ and $NP-hard$ can overshadow the actual problem; and by abuse of terminology, everyone knows what is meant by "in $NP$". e.g. question title also uses "$NP$". BTW: I stated it as a sequence of expansions/factorings because this is verifiable in P time - coming up with that sequence may take longer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think my problem is equivalent to arithmetic $+$ and $.$ with variables, if we exclude inverses. If Schwartz–Zippel is the best that can be done, and it requires inverses (subtraction), that seems to suggest that mine is a hard problem, and probably in $NP$. Does that seem right to you?

Comment: @hyperpallium "expanding it is NP, because just stating the answer takes exponential space" No! NP is nondeterministic polynomial time: if you're only using polynomial time, you're certainly not using exponential amounts of space. "Everyone knows what is meant by 'in NP'" I'm afraid you need to refresh the definition, there.

Comment: @DavidRicherby sorry, I'm not following. I meant that full expansion requires exponential symbols to state (e.g. $\Pi (x_i + y_i)$ expands to $2^n$ terms), and therefore exponential time to output it. Exponential time is worse than polynomial time. er... unless you mean that the sum-of-products algorithm isn't in $NP$ (as it has exponential terms, as you said in your first comment)?

Comment: @DavidRicherby maybe I should ask this question in terms of complexity, not $NP$. I just used $NP$ because it seems to be a well-developed body of knowledge and therefore might have an answer already.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I now realize that if I'm going to use $NP$, I actually do need to be clear on the defintions. I have reviewed the definitions a few times (just wikipedia and other web results), though I'm finding it difficult to fit my problem to it. Maybe it's not a good fit...?

Comment: @hyperpallium NP and coNP are not the same. For example, SAT is in NP but probably not in coNP. A language is in NP if there are witnesses for being *in* the language. It is in coNP if there are witnesses for being *outside* the language. In your case, an NP witness is a succinct proof that the two expressions are equivalent, while a coNP witness is a succinct proof that the two expressions are inequivalent. The latter is easier to imagine – some word which is accepted by one but not the other.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks, though I'm not grasping some terms, and I'm wondering if "is it in $NP$?" means "is it verifiable in polytime?" and not "is it a difficult problem?". I can't expect basic lessons here, but I'll list the terms and my understanding: *witness* - a solution to the problem that can be verified in P time; "*language is in NP"*" - I thought NP was for problems, not languages...? If we can find a witness in non-deterministic polynomial time that two expressions are inequivalent, doesn't a failure to find such a witness show they are equivalent? What's the flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: In the light comment feedback, I think I should change my question (1) **algebra**: use familiar high-school arithmetic (2+2=4, 2.3=6 etc) algebra, with $a$, $b$ etc  being variables and ask that answers not rely on inverses (substraction, division); (2) **complexity**: ask for proof that a polynomial time solution does not exist (or, for a polynomial time solution, if one does exist). Of course, answers might still use $NP${,-hard,-complete}, if it can be addressed that way.

Comment: Basic definitions: A problem is in **NP** if it can be verified in polynomial time. A problem that is **NP**-hard is "difficult", because if you could solve it in polynomial time you could solve any problem in **NP** in polynomial time. A problem that is both **NP**-hard and in **NP** is **NP**-complete. "Language" and "problem" are used more or less interchangeably. Failure to find a witness does indeed show they are equivalent. Nobody will be able to prove that a polynomial time solution doesn't exist (or they would have resolved a major open problem in theoretical computer science).

Comment: thanks @TomvanderZanden, that helps! But if failure to find a witness of inequivalence shows the expressions are equivalent, then either can be used to get the solution, so how do $NP$ and $coNP$ differ (for my problem)? I accept them as different approaches, that might inspire different algorithms. Yes, proving no polytime algorithm exists is real hard; but showing my problem is in one of the $NP$ classes ($NP$-hard seems the right now, for "difficult" problems) seemed possible, that would be close enough to "impossible" for me to stop worrying about it.

Comment: If you struggle with the basics, our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/845/98) may be helpful to you.

Comment: @hyperpallium Before asking if a language (i.e. a decision problem) is in NP, it's best if you understood what this means. Perhaps the reference questions that Raphael linked to would help.

Comment: Regarding $NP$ and $coNP$: For all practical purposes, expression equivalence and expression *in*equivalence are the same problem. But from a complexity theory perspective they're very different: I can convince you very easily that two expressions are inequivalent by demonstrating an input on which they evaluate to different values, but it might be very difficult to show that two expressions are equivalent. Failure to find a witness of inequivalence is proof that they are equivalent, but I can not present that proof in a succinct way. Whether $NP=coNP$ or not is another big open problem.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden I think I see what you're saying about succientness of proof, for different strategies.  But I don't see how it relates to my problem: if I had an algorithm to generate witnesses of *in*equivalence, then I could just run it, and if it didn't find any, that would prove equivalence. Though it seems quite possible, even likely, that the *complexity* of finding one witness of inequivalence is much lower than an exhaustive search to determine no such witness exists. (But could also be that worst-case finding the witness is the same complexity as determining none, so maybe NP=coNP)

Comment: @Raphael, YuvalFilmus thanks, I will study the complexity section.

Comment: You're looking at determining expression equivalence in a [semiring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring).  This is related to a [Kleene algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_algebra), which, in turn, is related to regular expressions.  It *might* be possible to reduce this problem to determining equivalence of regexes.  I'm out of my depth, but that might aid search terms.

Comment: @anorton thanks for the terminology! Checking, additive identity ($0$) is a multiplicative annihilator ($a.0=0.a=0$) so that aspect applies; but arithmetic algebra is actually a *commutative* semiring (because $ab=ba$). Unfortunately, this lack of ordering is a crucial difference from Kleene algebra/regular expressions (where $ab\neq ba$).

Comment: @TomvanderZanden after reading the reference questions, I think I understand your point about succientness now: if the witness has greater than $P$ length, it can't be verified in $P$ time, and so isn't in $NP$. If the witness exhaustively lists all the failures, it will have exponential length (and it's hard to see how to present it more briefly).

Comment: @hyperpallium : $\;\;\;$ Does your "no _coefficients_ other than 1" line refer to the expanded form? $\:$ If yes, then you might just have a [promise problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promise_problem), since I don't see any feasible way to check that requirement. $\:$ If no, what does that mean? $\:$ In any case, it may help that you are only dealing with _formulas_ rather than _circuits_. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer yes, the expanded form. Yes, an efficient *all one coefficients* algorithm seems difficult; actually, to me, the nub of it seems similar to this question itself. I suspect they are equivalent in some sense (if so, the promise problem would be begging the question.) I have an algorithm for checking *all one* which is OK for most common cases; but is exponential in the worst cases, which are rare... I *think*. I actually hadn't thought of asking it as a question here - maybe I should. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem reduces to zero testing of multivariate polynomials, for which there are efficient randomized algorithms.

Your expressions are all multivariate polynomials.  Apparently, your expressions are built up by the following rules: (a) if $x$ is a variable, then $x$ is an expression; (b) if $c$ is a constant, then $c$ is an expression; (c) if $e_1,e_2$ are expressions, then $e_1+e_2$ and $e_1e_2$ are expressions.  If that's indeed what you intended, every expression is a multivariate polynomial over the variables.

Now, you want to know if two expressions are equivalent.  This amounts to testing whether two multivariate polynomials are equivalent: given $p_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $p_2(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, you want to know if these two polynomials are equivalent.  You can test this by subtracting them and checking whether the result is identically zero: define

$$q(x_1,\dots,x_n) = p_1(x_1,\dots,x_n) - p_2(x_1,\dots,x_n).$$

Now $p_1,p_2$ are equivalent if and only if $q$ is the zero polynomial.

Testing whether $q$ is identically zero is the zero testing problem for multivariate polynomials.  There are efficient algorithms for that.  For instance, one example algorithm is to evaluate $q(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ at many random values of $x_1,\dots,x_n$.  If you find a value of $x_1,\dots,x_n$ such that $q(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, then you know that $q$ is not identically zero, i.e., $p_1,p_2$ are not equivalent.  If after many trials they are all zero, then you can conclude that $q$ is identically zero (if $q$ is not identically zero, the probability that all of those trials yield zero can be made exponentially low).  The number of iterations you need to do is related to the degree of $q$; see the literature on polynomial identity testing for details.

For instance, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz%E2%80%93Zippel_lemma and http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2009/11/30/the-curious-history-of-the-schwartz-zippel-lemma/

These algorithms apply if you are working over a finite field.  You didn't state what field/ring you are working in, and whether you are are treating these expressions as formal expressions (e.g., polynomials as abstract objects) or as functions from $\mathbb{F}^n \to \mathbb{F}$.  If you are working over a finite field, the methods above apply immediately.

If you're treating the expressions as formal objects, then your expressions are equivalent to multivariate polynomials with integer coefficients.  You can test equivalence of these by choosing a large random prime $r$ and testing equivalence modulo $r$, i.e., in the field $\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}$.  Repeat this polynomially many times, with different random values of $r$, and you should get an efficient randomized algorithm for testing equivalence of these formal expressions.

Comment: On the other hand, it would be [hard to prove](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00037-004-0182-6) that for each identically-zero expression, there is a not-too-long _proof_ that the expression is identically zero. $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer, great point!  Nice observation.  I interpreted the question as asking about testing equivalence rather than proving it, but that's a very nice observation.  (If you wanted to exhibit a proof of equivalence in practice, I suspect it's feasible to exhibit such a proof if you're willing to make cryptographic assumptions, for some definition of "proof" -- e.g., a scheme that achieves soundness in the random oracle model.)

Comment: Thanks! I'm treating them as formal objects, without inverses, division or subtraction (but using high school algebra for this question; seems more likely to be already solved). Do you mean, keep choosing large random primes $r$, and this is treating the expressions as if they were finite fields over the underlying set of integers $[0..r-1]$? That wiki link says there's no known sub-exponential *deterministic* algorithm for this zero-testing. Do you know if that applies to my problem?

Comment: @hyperpallium, yes exactly that's what I mean.  Yes, I believe that applies to your problem, too.  That's why I suggested a randomized algorithm -- there are efficient randomized algorithms, even though there are no known efficient deterministic algorithms.

Comment: As pointed out in a comment above, the OP is not working in a finite field, but rather a commutative semiring.  This means that additive inverses are not guaranteed to exist, so "subtracting" the expressions to check equality with zero is not a valid operation.

Comment: But, still +1, as this is closest result to the OP's problem I've seen yet.

Comment: I'm not fully clear on large prime $r$: that's just one integer, and we need $n$ integers, one for each $x_i$. How do we get those? Is it an inner loop of random integers for each $x_i$, selected from $[0..r-1]$? i.e. selecting an $r$ pretends we have a finite field modulo $r$; we then have several trials, each trial selecting values of the variables from $[0..1-r]$; then finally we choose another $r$ and repeat. BTW: does S-Z apply to high school algebra, which (I think) is an "infinite" field (because there are infinite integers)?

Comment: anorton: The Schwartz-Zippel idea was mentioned by @DavidRicherby but like you I thought it wouldn't work because my algebra doesn't have subtraction. But maybe we could treat it as if it did (a different algebra, over a different underlying set, which *is* equipped with a subtraction operator, but with the same commutative etc properties otherwise), just so we can use the algorithm - which I think is the proposal here.

Comment: @anorton, I think you've misunderstood things a bit.  The method I described here does work.  I suspect you've got mixed up what the ring is.  The coefficients here *are* in a field (e.g., $\mathbb{R}$).  The set of multivariate polynomials $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ is a ring, but that's not a problem for my method: what matters is that the coefficients are from a field $\mathbb{R}$.  Consequently, the method I described here *does* work.

Comment: @hyperpallium, one approach is to pick a random prime $r$, pick random values for $x_1,\dots,x_n$, evaluate $q(x_1,\dots,x_n) \bmod r$, and check whether it is zero or not.  Repeat that many times with a different random choice each time.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It's still surprising to me that there's no known (deterministic) short-cut to such a simple and old problem... which I guess is why rjlipton (in your linked article) keeps looking.

Comment: Turns out Zippel commented on that blog post! Saying 10 years later he (and others, independently) found a *deterministic* polynomial time algorithm (using a different complexity measure...), though it's slower in practice than the probablistic one. http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2009/11/30/the-curious-history-of-the-schwartz-zippel-lemma/#comment-6106 (nb: this permalink isn't working on my phone, a search for "polynomial time" hits only that comment)

Comment: @hyperpallium, yeah, but that's sort of like saying "yes, pigs *can* fly, as long as you define an airplane as a pig".  The result you are referring to is not relevant to the problem statement here, where the expressions are given in unexpanded form.  Indeed, your original question even mentions that a straightforward algorithm for your problem would be to expand the expressions to get a sum of monomials and then check directly for equivalence, but that can take exponential time, so it's no good.  For the same reason, the deterministic algorithm you mention is also no good.

Comment: I got them impression too, but I wasn't sure it really did involve full expansion (it seemed to from the blog comment, but I wasn't sure). It seems like a changing the goalposts unreasonably, but I guess it's relevant for some other application of the problem. Also, I've found some more research on more constrained versions of the problem (multilinear; read-once; constant-read; depth-3 algorithmic circuits), and some seem close to my constraints. I've clarified them in the question. Seems an active research topic!

Comment: @hyperpallium, yes, it's an active research area.  My solution works with all of the constraints you list in your question.

Comment: Yes, I know; thanks! I've upvoted and accepted your answer. Although each trial reduces the chance of error by $d/r$, making it as small as you like, real fast, I feel more comfortable with deterministic algorithms - and those constraints might make it possible (though from my initial skims of that research, it seems to be doing things I'd already thought of). I think a deterministic version would also help in indicating where and how exactly the expressions mismatch. But if I really want that, I guess I should open a new question, as this specific one is answered.

Comment: I think I should pare back this particular question, removing my constraints, so it is just about one specific issue, making it more useful to future readers. And open a followup question, asking for a deterministic solution, given those constraints (which I don't think exists).

Comment: Implementation: I hacked a bare implementation, and found it difficult to make it fail (even one trial yield zeo when they weren't equivalent): I ended up having to design $p_1$ and $p_2$ so $q$ had roots, then choose $r$ very small ($101$ worked), so a higher chance of hitting that root. (Though small 'test' expressions have few roots; it would be easier to hit zero in an expression with thousands of variables).

Comment: How bad is it if $r$ isn't prime? I'm using java's `BigInteger.probablePrime()` I don't think it would cause an erroneous non-zero (i.e. showing $\neq$ when $=$) I think finite fields aren't defined for modulo non-prime? Since Schwartz-Zippel works for $\mathbb{Z}$, is modulo $r$ just for efficiency? Also, generating primes is slow - how bad is it to reuse primes? Or use `BigInteger.nextProbablePrime()` (instead of completely random)? And, is 64 bit 'large'? Maybe I should open a follow-up 'implementation' question as well...

Comment: @hyperpallium, good question!  I believe the modulo $r$ is just for efficiency.  I *think* it should work fine without any modular reduction, working with integers.  And yes it's fine to work modulo a random number that passes `BigInteger.isProbablePrime()` -- set the `certainty` level to something like `80` or so, and the probability that it's not prime is so small as to be negligible (a cosmic ray error is more likely than getting a non-prime).  Yes, 64 bits is large.  Yes, I suggest following up with a separate implementation question, if you want help calculating specific parameters.

Comment: @hyperpallium : $\:$ Yes, do ask a separate implementation question. $\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on the **one-power**, **one-coefficent** and **one-constants** constraints in the question:

These define a subset the problem of polynomial identity testing. Clearly, they can be solved with a technique that solves the general problem. The question is whether they form a subset that is more easily solved.

**one-coefficient**: in problems without this, terms might be combined, making the problem easier. Consider the Binomial Theorem/Pascal's triangle for $(a+b)^n$. This can be expanded one factor at a time, producing terms with overlapping orders e.g. $(a+b)(a+b) = aa+ab+ab+bb = aa+2ab+bb$ The fewer terms make it easier to expand with the next factor: $(aa+2ab+bb)(a+b) = aaa+2aab+abb + aab+2abb+bbb = aaa+3aab+3abb+bbb$ and again terms are combined, making a smaller simpler problem. This combining of terms is a form of dynamic programming.

That is, the possibility of combining terms, creating a non-one coefficient, makes the problem easier not harder.

(Although there is more work in calculation in multiplying non-one coefficients)

**non-one constants** are included in the above argument by considering constants as variables with zero exponent.

**one-power** I don't think this makes any difference. Although non-one exponents can be created in more than one way (e.g. $a^4=a^2a^2=a^1a^3$), and this can lead to overlap and combination (as in the Binomial Theorm/Pascal's triangle above), actual combination is only possible if non-one coefficients are allowed.

The above is not a formal or rigorous argument. It rests on an assumption about what makes the problem difficult. But it does seem to me that combining terms only makes for an easier problem - so preventing this by the **one coefficient** constraint is not going to make the subset easier.